# ViewModel LiveData in android not working

Tags: android, viewmodel

I just learned about liveata viewmodel. I have an object, the main_activity consists of 2 fragments, in which when I change the value of ControlFragment, the value on DetailFragment will change. But It not work , while I change the value in fragment control, the value in fragment 2 does not change.

Please, help me fix issue

ViewModelMedal

```
public class ViewModelMedal extends ViewModel {
public MutableLiveData<Integer> numberGold = new MutableLiveData<>();
public MutableLiveData<Integer> numberSilver = new MutableLiveData<>();
public MutableLiveData<Integer> numberBronze = new MutableLiveData<>();

public ViewModelMedal() {
    numberGold.setValue(0);
    numberSilver.setValue(0);
    numberBronze.setValue(0);
}
```

}

ControlFragment.java

```
public class ControlFragmentJava extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button btnGold, btnGoldPlus, btnSilver, btnSilverPlus, btnCu, btnCuPlus;
private TextView tvGold, tvSilver, tvBronze;
private ViewModelMedal mViewModelMedal;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_control, container, false);
    mViewModelMedal = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModelMedal.class);

    .
    .
    .

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnBronzePlus:
            mViewModelMedal.numberCBronze.setValue(mViewModelMedal.numberCu.getValue()+1);
            initSetData();
            break;
        case R.id.btnBronzeMinus:
            mViewModelMedal.numberBronze.setValue(mViewModelMedal.numberCu.getValue()-1);
            initSetData();
            break;
        case R.id.btnGoldMinus:
            mViewModelMedal.numberGold.setValue(mViewModelMedal.numberGold.getValue()-1);
            initSetData();
            break;
        case R.id.btnGoldPlus:
            mViewModelMedal.numberGold.setValue(mViewModelMedal.numberGold.getValue()+1);
            initSetData();
            break;
        case R.id.btnSilverMinus:
            mViewModelMedal.numberSilver.setValue(mViewModelMedal.numberSilver.getValue()-1);
            initSetData();
            break;
        case R.id.btnSilverPlus:
            mViewModelMedal.numberSilver.setValue(mViewModelMedal.numberSilver.getValue()+1);
            initSetData();
            break;

    }

}
```

}

DetailFragment

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {
public ViewModelMedal mViewModelMedal;
private TextView tvGold, tvSilver, tvBronze;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail,container,false);
    tvBronze = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDetailBronzeNumber);
    tvGold = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDetailGoldNumber);
    tvSilver = view.findViewById(R.id.tvDetailSilverNumber);
    mViewModelMedal = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ViewModelMedal.class);
    mViewModelMedal.numberBronze.observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
            tvCu.setText(String.valueOf(mViewModelMedal.numberCu.getValue()));
        }
    });
    mViewModelMedal.numberGold.observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
            tvGold.setText(String.valueOf(mViewModelMedal.numberGold.getValue()));
        }
    });
    mViewModelMedal.numberSilver.observe(this, new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Integer integer) {
            tvSilver.setText(String.valueOf(mViewModelMedal.numberSilver.getValue()));
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Is your `onChanged()` method called? You need to set the argument value you get from the `onChanged()` method and not do a `getValue()`. That defeats the purpose of LiveData.

Comment: Are the fragments using the same instance of the view model or each fragment creates a new instance? You need to make sure you are using the same instance

Answer (score 0):

The issue is pretty simple here: you have two instances of the `ViewModelMedal` class as you use the two fragments as the `ViewModelStoreOwner` in the `ViewModelProviders.of(this)` calls. What might help you is using the parent `Activity` to manage the view model by calling `ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity())`.

*Note that the [`ViewModelProviders`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders) class is deprecated as stated by the message on its page:*

> **This class is deprecated.**
>
> Use the constructors for [`ViewModelProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider) directly.